# Does locally DVR implies Dedekind Domain when it is 1-dimensional, semi-local domain but Noetherian not given

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, dedekind-domain, dimension-theory-algebra

> Let R be a semi-local integral domain of dimension 1 such that $\forall P \in Spec{R} $ such that $P \ne 0$ we have, $R_P$ to be a Discrete Valuation Ring. Then prove that $R$ is a Dedekind Domain?

If it was given that $R$ is Noetherian then I know that it would follow that, a Noetherian domain of dimension 1 which is locally DVR $\implies$ it is a Dedekind Domain. But I am not sure how to get the Noetherian property from the localisations to the ring $R$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried the case of a ring with two maximal ideals, since the local case is trivial?

Comment: @Mohan In order to show that $R$ is Noetherian it is enough to show that all the prime ideals are finitely generated (Since then we can apply Cohen's theorem). Now $R_P$ is a DVR gives that $PR_P$ is principal, $\forall P \in Spec R$ . But that's the extension of the prime ideals in the localisations, how to get back to P's with this argument?

Answer (score 2):

I expand my comment. So assume $R$ has just two maximal ideals, $P,Q$. Let us show that $P$ is finitely generated.  One knows $PR_P, PR_Q$ are both finitely generated (in fact, in your case one generated). So, you can find (by clearing denominators), $x,y\in P$ such that $xR_P=PR_P, yR_Q=PR_Q$. Then, obviously $(x,y)R_P=PR_P$ and $(x,y)R_Q=PR_Q$. Now, can you show that $(x,y)R=P$?

Comment: Yes, by Local-Global principles.